# Resolving a recipient given SMTP domain and partial name

Tags: vba, outlook, smtp

According to the Default Global Address List in Outlook 2010:

1. a recipient named "John Doe" is assigned the email address "john@aaa.com"
2. a recipient named "John Doe2" is assigned the email address "doe@bbb.com"

If "John Doe" is typed into the [To] field and [Send] is pressed, Outlook seems to find the name "John Doe" ambiguous, thereby the user is forced to pick the exact name label (via [Check Names] button) before the mailitem can actually be sent.

My goal is to automatically select the correct (1) name label or (2) the email address of the recipient, given the knowledge of the domain and partial name.

The problem is, we only know the recipient having:

1. a name going by "John Doe" which is not resolvable by itself (due to "John Doe2") and
2. a specific domain (@aaa.com or @bbb.com), but not the full email address.

The name label "John Doe2" is unknown until "John Doe" is somehow resolved of course.

If we have knowledge of the domain and partial knownledge of the recipient's name, would it be possible to get:

1) Full Name (must be resolved) or

2) Full SMTP address (preferable choice because it is unambiguous)

of the recipient, such that the mailitem becomes sendable?

```
Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
Dim domaintype As String                ' domaintype is given
'   domaintype = "@aaa.com"
'   domaintype = "@bbb.com"
Dim recipientname As String             ' recipient name is partially known
'   recipientname = "John Doe"

if domaintype = "@aaa.com" then
    With Email
        ' How do I add the correct recipient?
        .Recipient.Add recipientname    ' SMTP address = john@aaa.com for "John Doe"
    End With
elseif domaintype = "@bbb.com" then
    With Email
        ' How do I add the correct recipient?
        .Recipient.Add recipientname    ' SMTP address = doe@bbb.com for "John Doe2"
    End With
else
    ' do something else
end if

Email.Recipients.ResolveAll     ' "John Doe" is not resolved because it is ambiguous!
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Object Model would not let you silently retrieve a list of ambiguous matches.

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can use [PR_ANR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/address-book-restrictions) restriction on the contents table of the containers (IABContainer) in the Address Book search path.

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its developer) - you can use [RDOAddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`ResolveNameEx` method - it returns a list of matching entries:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.ResolveNameEx("John")
Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
Debug.Print "------------"
for each AE in AdrrEntries
    Debug.Print AE.Name & " " & AE.SMTPAddress
next
Debug.Print "------------"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code. Could you please provide the DIM types for: Session, AdrrEntries, AE? The program does not seem to work.

Comment: Session - RDOSession, AddrEntries - RDOAddressEntries, AE - RDOAddressEntry.

Comment: I see... so it is not native VBA. I'm afraid the firm does not allow for such downloads. I will have to stick to VBA only. Thanks anyways.

Comment: OOM alone won't let you do that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddressEntry_From_Ambiguous_Name()

    ' Please note.
    ' It is not practical to loop through a GAL.
    ' This is for science.

    ' This is a demo for finding names by looping through the GAL.
    ' There is more coding to do if you insist.

    Dim oAL As AddressList
    Dim colAE As AddressEntries
    Dim oAE As AddressEntry
    Dim oExUser As exchangeUser

    Dim i As Long

    Dim maxCount As Long
    Dim testCount As Long
    Dim srchName As String
    Dim candidateName As String

    ' For testing stay near the top of the list
    srchName = "Abc"

    ' This condition is left for you to code
    'srchDomain = "aaa.com"

    Set oAL = Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")

    'Address list is an Exchange Global Address List
    If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then

        Set colAE = oAL.AddressEntries

        maxCount = colAE.count

        ' For testing
        testCount = 1000
        If maxCount > testCount Then maxCount = testCount
        ' comment out above two lines to go live

        For i = 1 To maxCount

            ' no distribution lists
            If colAE(i).AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry _
              Or colAE(i).AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry Then

                Debug.Print i & " colAE(i).name: " & colAE(i).name

                ' Where name is in Last, First format in the GAL
                ' You can Split at the comma instead.
                candidateName = Left(colAE(i).name, Len(srchName))

                If candidateName = srchName Then

                    Set oExUser = colAE(i).GetExchangeUser

                    If MsgBox((oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress) & " is this the address.", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                        Debug.Print (oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress) & " found."
                        Debug.Print "Code to replace the recipient, without using MsgBox."
                        Exit For
                    End If

                    DoEvents

                ElseIf candidateName > srchName Then

                    Set oExUser = colAE(i).GetExchangeUser
                    Debug.Print i & " " & oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    Debug.Print " You have gone past last name " & srchName
                    Debug.Print " Code to delete the recipient then send."
                    Exit For

                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```